# passing parameter ,@using (Html.BeginForm )from dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following code , and i want to pass selected value from dropdownlist , when i submit button , the value of parameter should be read from selectedvalue rather than "1"

```
<td style="width:25%;">
    @Html.DropDownList( "ClientTypeId", null, new {@class="table",style="width: 70%; height:100%;"})
</td>
<td style="width:25%;">
</td>
<td style="width:25%;">
</td>
<td style="width:25%;">
     @using (Html.BeginForm("View", "Client", new { ClientTypeId =  1 }, FormMethod.Post, null))
     {
          <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default"  />
     }
</td>
```

Comment: my dropdownlist code :  @Html.DropDownList( "ClientTypeId", null, new {@class="table",style="width: 70%; height:100%;"})

Comment: Your dropdown needs to be **inside** the form (and remove `new { ClientTypeId =  1 }` from the form)

Comment: thank you , it's work fine now :)
     @ using (Html.BeginForm("View", "Client",  FormMethod.Post, null))
                                 {
                                             @ Html.DropDownList("ClientTypeId", null, new { @class = "table", style = "width: 70%; height:100%;" })
                                     
                                                  <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default"  />
                                 
                                 }

Comment: @StephenMuecke , thank ,you , it's work fine , but i want to ask you , if i want to pass many parameters ? , in my case i want to pass value from <input type="text" id="ClientName"> + the the value of DropList Named "ClientTypeId"

how can i do that ??

Comment: Then you just need to add an input for that as well. A form will post back all the `name/value` pairs of its successful controls.

Comment: @StephenMuecke
when i replace <input type="text" id="ClientName">
with
@ Html.TextBox("ClientName", null, new { @ class = "input input-group-sm" })
the code work fine ! what is the different between them ?!

Comment: You manual html does not have a `name` attribute so there is nothing to post back (but always use the strongly typed `***For()` methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Add your dropdown list inside form(@using (Html.BeginForm)) tag. You will get your data.